# How to config django to support bulk_create with mysql upsert?

Tags: mysql, django

```
CREATE TABLE `extras` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_st` tinyint NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `fk_date_code` (`date`,`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

Installed python packages:

```
# pip list installed
Package                      Version
---------------------------- ------------
asgiref                      3.7.2
Django                       4.2.5
django-bulk-update-or-create 0.3.0
djangorestframework          3.14.0
pip                          21.2.3
PyMySQL                      1.1.0
pytz                         2023.3.post1
setuptools                   53.0.0
sqlparse                     0.4.4
typing_extensions            4.7.1
```

I checked MySQL with follow SQL with success:

```
INSERT INTO extras (`date`, `code`, `is_st`)
VALUES ('2013-01-04', '000001.XSHE', 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
is_st = 1;
```

But when call `MyModel.objects.bulk_create`, it reports error:

> File
> "env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line
> 87, in manager_method
> return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)   File "env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line
> 773, in bulk_create
> on_conflict = self._check_bulk_create_options(   File "env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line
> 696, in _check_bulk_create_options
> raise NotSupportedError(
> django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: This database backend does not
> support updating conflicts with specifying unique fields that can
> trigger the upsert.

Just had a look at the source files:

> ## find env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django -type f | xargs grep "supports_update_conflicts_with_target"
>
> env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/features.py:
> supports_update_conflicts_with_target = False grep:
> env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/**pycache**/features.cpython-39.pyc: binary file matches
> env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/features.py:
> supports_update_conflicts_with_target = True grep:
> env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/**pycache**/features.cpython-39.pyc:
> binary file matches
> env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/features.py:
> supports_update_conflicts_with_target = supports_update_conflicts
> env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py:
> and self.connection.features.supports_update_conflicts_with_target
> grep:
> env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/**pycache**/features.cpython-39.pyc:
> binary file matches grep:
> env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/**pycache**/operations.cpython-39.pyc:
> binary file matches
> env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:
> if unique_fields and not
> db_features.supports_update_conflicts_with_target:
> env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:
> if not unique_fields and
> db_features.supports_update_conflicts_with_target: grep:
> env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/**pycache**/query.cpython-39.pyc:
> binary file matches

It seems that in my installation, env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py doesn't contain config for `supports_update_conflicts_with_target`.

Comment: please add your table as well please

Comment: Do I need to install `django-mysql` to support upsert?

Comment: that is no django error, i think , so show a create table and we can reproduce it

Comment: @nbk I have added the creation script in topic.

Comment: That could be a bug, see here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py

Comment: try django_mysql or ,myql_connector

Comment: @nbk have you tried? It seems that it is a django bug, it mysql's features file, it doesn't overwirte supports_update_conflicts_with_target attribute which is default False.

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe a bug in django.

I made some changes:

1. add `supports_update_conflicts_with_target = True` to `django/db/backends/mysql/features.py`
2. Remove `unique_together` from `MyModel.Meta`, add `constraints` instead.

Then, it works like a bulk operation.

Comment: I can see a bulk insertion, but I can not see the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause.